# Change Libraries's position in Navigation Pane

Tags: windows-8.1

In Windows 8.1 the Libraries is now hidden by default, and if I choose to display it, it is displayed *under* Computer and the drives, as oppose to *above* in previous versions of Windows:

[image]

Is it possible to change the position of the Libraries in the Navigation Pane? I want it to be between Favorites and Computer, just like before.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the solution is in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2A5uKahw4Uk).

This program can remove and add items into navigation pane. Maybe if you remove all your items and add them in your order it works.

Comment: YouTube videos tend to be removed without notice. Can you explain the steps in the video so if the video is removed your answer is still helpful? What program are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the utility posted by user264483 to work, but I found [this site](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/33844-libraries-move-above-pc-windows-8-1-a.html) offering a registry modification that worked for me in Windows 8.1

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{031E4825-7B94-4dc3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}]
"SortOrderIndex"=dword:00000042
```

Add this to a .reg file and run it, or manually edit that key in RegEdit.